# Github Rest API only giving the word Error on catch

Tags: reactjs, github-api

I have a React app I am making. I am trying to use various parts of Githubs Rest API. I am unsure what else to say other then the below code only gives me the word "Error" in the console. I don't get a specific error or anything, and I am unsure how to get a more detailed error message.

```
import { Octokit } from "@octokit/rest";
import { createAppAuth } from "@octokit/auth-app";

export const octokit = new Octokit({
    authStrategy: createAppAuth,
    auth: {
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_APPID,
        privateKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_PRIVATEKEY,
        clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENTID,
        clientSecret: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENTSECRET,
        installationId: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_INSTALLATIONID,
    },
});
```

```
    const getRepoFiles = async (owner, repo) => {
            let path = 'composer.json';
            await octokit.request(`GET /repos/${owner}/${repo}/contents/${path}`, {
                owner: 'OWNER',
                repo: 'REPO',
                path: 'PATH',
                headers: {
                  'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
getRepoFiles();
```

Comment: try `getRepoFiles().catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: Theres already a catch in the function. that's what is giving me the string in the console log. I went ahead and moved the catch to where you said and it just gives the same thing.

Comment: Try looking at the network tab in your browser to see what the URL is being called by Octokit. It should also give you an HTTP error code which can help diagnose the issue here.